# Merge repository into clone with modifications

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

We have a local repository of a project, which we cloned from an online-repo some months ago and decoupled it. We made quite a few changes. Now the original repository released a new version, which we would like to merge into our clone, while keeping our modifications (or resolve conflicts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility, instead of merging, would be to rebase your own code on top of the newest state of the online repository.
Make sure to do so with a new temporary branch, for checking how it goes.
If this work, you will need to warn your colleagues that you are force pushing an existing branch, and they will need to reset.

```
 git remote add upstream /url/of/original/old/repo
 git fetch upstream
 git checkout -b integration
 git rebase upstream/master
```

Comment: I thought of that (actually I read it somewhere), but was not too confident rebase actually does what we needed here, after reading some online articles about it. Will try it now though, thanks!